# Having trouble defining asyncio function argument

Tags: python, websocket

I'm setting a python websocket client that should make send and receive request's as described:

1. Connect to the websocket.
2. Send the request to get current timestamp.
3. Receive back the current timestamp.
4. Compare times , if times are synced continue, if not reply ("not_synced!").
5. Send the machine name (in this case it is defined in the config file)
6. The server response back with a timestamp in the future when it is
7. Expecting a ping, the time is saved in config file
8. Close connection and wait for current time to match the time in the future!

By now, I have perfectly created functions for reading/saving in strings in the config file, comparing the received time with current time.

The only issue I can`t figure out how to solve it's the communication to the server, actually I want to define one function that should do all the communication through.

Tried defining function without asyncio, I couldn't return received message.
While using asyncio, I couldn't pass the argument in function (actually the message string!)

```
import asyncio
import websockets


async def connect(msg):
    async with websockets.connect("ws://connect.websocket.in    /xnode?room_id=19210") as socket: # the opencfg function reads a file, in this case, line 4 of config file where url is stored
        await socket.send(msg)
    result =await socket.recv()
    return result
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(connect())


def connect2(msg):
    soc= websockets.connect("ws://connect.websocket.in    /xnode?room_id=19210")
    soc.send(msg)
    result=soc.recv()
    return result

print(connect2("gettime"))
```

If you would try to send "gettime" , you will receive back the current timestamp, and after sending the "|online" you should receive back a value  that is equal to current timestamp + 10.

You have the websocketurl so try it for yourself.

Comment: It's **receive** - not "recive" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your code to use `asynio.gather` to get the return value and passed `"gettime"` to the function:

```py
import asyncio
import websockets

address = "ws://connect.websocket.in/xnode?room_id=19210"

async def connect(msg):
    async with websockets.connect(address) as socket:
        await socket.send(msg)
        result = await socket.recv()
    return result
result = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(connect("gettime")))
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['1564626191']
```

You can reuse the code by putting it into a function definition:

```py
def get_command(command):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    result = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(connect(command)))
    return result

result = get_command("gettime")
print(result)
```

Comment: Okay , but how can i use this function to send and recieve another command ?

Comment: I added some code to the answer showing how you can put the whole thing into a function definition so you can reuse it.

Comment: I belive i am doing something wrong , after i send the first msg(command) and use the function get_command("|online") i get the same result as previous message?

Comment: While the command is sending , and my server replies back , i can`t print them out in python :(

Comment: Yeah, there was an error in `get_command`. It seems to work now.